# Disabling F5 key on ListPage AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to disable the F5 refresh on a specific listpage, I disabled the refresh action key but the F5 still works. I can't overide the Task method on the SysSetupFormRun because it's a listpage. Is any way to do this?

The reason I want to do this is because some refreshproblems when having multiple datasources and I want to disable it for the customer until microsoft comes with a solution (issue is already logged).

Edit: 
As a fix I intercepted the task method on the SysSetupFormRun class, but this method only triggers when you have selected a record in your listpage. When you first open your listpage and immediately press F5 it does refresh and doesn't go in the task method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you mentioned that you had no success with overwriting `task` of `SysSetupFormRun`, but the code below worked for me in our test system.

I inserted this code into method `task` of class `SysSetupFormRun` to disable F5 for `SalesTableListPage`:

```
public int task(int _p1)
{
    #task
    FormDataSource formDataSource;

    int ret;

    if (_p1 == #taskFilter)
    {
        formDataSource = this.objectSet();
        if (formDataSource &&
            formDataSource.queryRun() &&
            formDataSource.queryRun().args() &&
            !formDataSource.queryRun().args().caller())
        {
            formDataSource.queryRun().args().caller(this);
        }
    }

    // -- Here is the interesting stuff
    if ((_p1 == #taskF5 || _p1 == #taskRefresh) && 
        (this.name() == formStr(SalesTableListPage)))
    {
        return ret;
    }
    return super(_p1);
}
```

If the approach is the same as the one you already tried, then you can ignore this answer - otherwise feel free to try it out ;)

Comment: Thanks this is the solution, I was actually thinking the same thing after reading some blogposts but I put a breakpoint in the class and it didn't trigger (now it does, probably did something wrong :S). So I thought it wouldn't be a solution, stupid actually.

Comment: `code`
    if((_p1 == #taskF5) && (this.name() == formStr(smmActivitiesListPage)))
    {
        return ret;
    }
    
    ret = super(_p1);

    return ret;
} `code`

Comment: After testing this I noticed that when you immediately press F5 when the listpage opens and you didn't select one record, the Task method will not trigger and the refresh will take place. This is probably why my debugger didn't went into the task method when I first tested it to see if it could be a solution.

Comment: I edited the answer: I could reproduce the behavior when pressing F5 at form startup. In my AX environment it is possible to prevent this when also checking for #taskRefresh; method 'task' seems to be called with #taskRefresh when no record is selected, otherwise it is called with #taskF5.

Comment: This does it for me, thanks. Now hope Microsoft fixes the original issue :)